# How to disable "Table rates" if free shipping is avaiable on checkout - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, free-shipping

How can i disable "Table Rates" Shipping method on checkout if "Free Shipping" is avaiable?

Comment: any solution on that?